# Stream Records in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I started reading about dynamodb and came across concept of Dynamodb streams I have a doubt If we delete an item from dynamodb does a stream record is generated for that item in dynamodb streams? If yes how will the stream record will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

You can find all information related to the stream events format and schema in the documentation. The link for what you need is this [one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html).

In summary, all dynamoDB records have a eventName property that can have one of three values: 'INSERT', 'MODIFY' or 'REMOVE'. Besides that you can configure your stream to send the event content when the event occur. For the DELETE event, for example, you can receive the entire Object content inside the event, if you configured the Stream for this.